# Есть ли возможность обработать исходящую SMS до её непосредственной отправки адресату?

Tags: java, android, sms

Всем привет!
Вопрос в том, как перехватить отправляемую смс, чтобы например блокировать её или как-то изменить текст - порезать нецензурщину, например :)
Поиск в интернете результатов пока не дал. Хотя ищу полдня уже.
Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей и знает, как оно делается?

Comment: пффф, пол-дня он ищет.. хорошие решения можно по пол-года искать! а то и вовсе не найти..

Comment: так это понятно. обидно, однако, что вроде бы должно быть на поверности по аналогии с получением входящих смс. но почему-то это не так...
да и важно не рещение целиком а стратегия действия. в каком направлении рыть :)

Comment: Это делается на одном из узлов ss7 роутинга провайдера сотовой связи на пути ее доставки в SMS-центр.

Comment: пацтулам... :):):)
ну в плане что мне до того узла не достучаться ну никак. а вот со своего телефона отправляемые смс до ухода к узлам провайдера хотелось бы перехватывать уметь...:):):)

Comment: Barmaley, имеется в виду решение с мониторингом папки исходящих смс?
Если оно, то я его пока делать не буду, т.к. оно не особо актуально на данный момент. Может, быть сделаю потом, когда добью остальной функционал приложения. Тогда и выложу.
Потом попробую поковырять вариант с 4-м андроидом, где якобы есть возможность непосредственно перехватить смс до отправки его во вне. 
Если получится, тоже выложу.
Но мне актуальнее вариант со 2-м андроидом, т.к. ещё масса девайсов работает на версиях ниже 4-й. Хочется сделать,чтобы приложение по максимуму было совместимо с разными весиями андоида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой недокументированный бродкаст: `android.intent.action.NEW_SENDING_SMS` - попробуйте половите его.

**Update на свежую голову**

С вероятностью 99% все равно не поможет, поскольку посылка бродкаста и отсылка СМС проходят параллельно. В общем, скорее всего, это невозможно. Ну или есть еще какой-то недокументированный бродкаст/сервис, который можно половить и попробовать остановить. Надо копаться в исходниках Android'а и/или брать реальный девайс подключать его к отладчику и копаться в кишках логов - смотреть/анализировать.

Comment: не ловится что-то  android.intent.action.SENDING_SMS
:(

Comment: Я ошибся, надо ловить `NEW_SENDING_SMS` [посмотрите сюда](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2_r1/com/android/mms/InterceptSendSms.java)

Comment: там если присмотреться происходит следующее:

mInterceptReceiver = new InterceptSmsReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WorkingMessage.ACTION_SENDING_SMS);
activity.registerReceiver(mInterceptReceiver, filter);

а WorkingMessage.ACTION_SENDING_SMS есть не что иное, как android.intent.action.SENDING_SMS

которое у меня почему-то тоже не ловится :(
печаль...

Comment: А вы добавляете перехватчик в манифесте с экспортом?

Comment: я перехватчик создаю программно в коде сервиса.
или этого недостаточно?

по крайней мере для исходящих звонков событие в аналогичном перехватчике, созданном в коде сервиса, ловится нормально без добавления чего-либо в манифест.

Comment: В общем, после двухдневного битья о стену, вроде бы удалось выяснить, что возможность перехвата исходящих смс должна быть начиная с API17 или 18, т.е. минимум в версии Android 4.3.
Печально...
Я-то пытаюсь работать с вторым андроидом.
А там видимо никак это не одолеть, чтобы было красиво. Только следить за изменениями в папке исходящих смс. Но это как бы ни туда и ни сюда, т.к. смс уже ушло... мертовму припарка...

Comment: @Demon051 выложи свое решение в виде отдельного ответа. Народу будет интересно, а уж мне втройне.